# Struts 2.5 Unable to find taglib [s] for URI: [/struts-tags]

Tags: struts2, tomcat8, struts2-tiles-plugin

Trying to migrate Struts 2.1 5o 2.5 and Tomcat 6 to Tomcat 8. 
Struts tiles plug in 2.1 to 2.5. once deployed into Tomcat 8 JSP is not displaying and getting this error.

**Type Exception Report

Message ServletException including path '/pages/tiles/defaultPageLayout.jsp'.

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

org.apache.tiles.request.render.CannotRenderException: ServletException including path '/pages/tiles/defaultPageLayout.jsp'. **

in the log 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] threw exception
 org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to find taglib [s] for URI: [/struts-tags]

Comment: Taglibs are in the core library

Comment: Do you have `struts2-core-.jar` in `WEB-INF/lib` of deployed app?

Comment: Yes struts2-core-.jar in WEB-INF/lib it there

Comment: Maybe it's not being scanned in catalina.properties?  Might need to include it in `tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToScan`

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue along seemingly random with 404 errors and the only thing that fixed it for me was to do the following :

- Delete the **.m2 folder** in C:\Users\%USERNAME%\
- Right-click the
  project : Maven -> Update Project -> Force update of
  snapshots/Release
- Run Maven clean/install